# how to pass query parameter in resolve method

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-route

Here is my js code

```
var MYApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'myAppServices', 'ngSanitize'])    
    .config(myRouter);


angular.module('myAppServices', ['ngResource'])
    .factory('GridsAPI', function($resource) {
        return {
            GetUser: $resource('/MY/system/getUser/:id')
        };
    });
function ViewUserController($scope, user) {

}
function myRouter($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider
        .when('/users/view/:id', {
            templateUrl: '/MY/system/users/view/:id',
            controller: 'ViewUserController',
            resolve: {
                user: function(GridsAPI) {
                    //how to return user based on id passed to this url?
                }
            }
        });
}
```

I want to get the user via ajax call before the view has loaded, how can I get the id parameter in resolve?

Comment: $routeParams should also work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inject `$route` and then:

```
resolve: {
    user: ['$route', 'GridsAPI', function($route, GridsAPI) {
      var userId = $route.current.params.id;
      ...
    }]
}
```

Comment: Where, and how should the $route service be injected ?? This answer needs more code...